# Passing variables into a string variable that contains json

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, json.net

I am trying to replace some parts of my query with a variable that holds a certain value.

For instance, inside of my variable `query` I am wanting to replace

- `\"level\": \"Information\"`
- and `\"match\": { \"level\": \"Error\"`
- with variable `fieldName` and variable `fieldValue` respectively

  - The `fieldName` holds a value of `"_source.level"`
  - and `fieldValue` holds a value of `"information"` and `"error"`.

(Not sure if I have to make another variable to hold the
second value of "error" since I am wanting both information and
error.)

The issue I am running into is normally I know you would add a `$` before the string and add a `{}` where you want to call the variable. However, when I add a `$` at the beginning of my string it does not like it and says

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

So I am facing issues trying to figure out how I can pass those variables into my query variable.

```cs
string jsonFromFile;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    jsonFromFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VirtualSupport>(jsonFromFile);


foreach (var item in json.Systems.Applications)
{
    foreach (var x in item.Application)
    {
        foreach (var y in x.BusinessProcessSteps)
        {
            foreach (var z in y.BusinessProcessStep.LogDataSources)
            {
                var fieldName = z.LogDataSource.LogFieldsMapping.LevelField.FieldName;
                var fieldValue = z.LogDataSource.LogFieldsMapping.LevelField.FieldValue;
            }
        }
    }
}

var query = "{\"size\": 1000,\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"should\":[ {\"match\": { \"level\": \"Information\" } }, {\"match\": { \"level\": \"Error\" } } ], " +
            "\"filter\": [ { \"range\": { \"@timestamp\": { \"gte\": \"2021-07-26T07:58:45.304-05:00\", \"lt\": \"2021-07-26T08:58:45.305-05:00\" } } } ]," +
            "\"minimum_should_match\": 1 } } }";
```

Snippet of the json file that I am reading from and assigning `fieldname` and `fieldvalue` to.

```json
"LogFieldsMapping": {
    "IDField": { "FieldName": "_id" },
    "LevelField": {
        "FieldName": "_source.level",
        "FieldValue": [
            { "value": "Information" },
            { "value": "Error" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then using the `$` (string interpolation), you could consider converting the `query`-string into a class:

```json
{
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "level": "Information"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "level": "Error"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2021-07-26T07:58:45.304-05:00",
                            "lt": "2021-07-26T08:58:45.305-05:00"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be converted to something like this:

```cs
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Match
    {
        public string level { get; set; }
    }

    public class Should
    {
        public Match match { get; set; }
    }

    public class Timestamp
    {
        public DateTime gte { get; set; }
        public DateTime lt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Range
    {
        [JsonProperty("@timestamp")]
        public Timestamp Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        public Range range { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bool
    {
        public List<Should> should { get; set; }
        public List<Filter> filter { get; set; }
        public int minimum_should_match { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        public Bool @bool { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int size { get; set; }
        public Query query { get; set; }
    }
```

You can instanciate a new object from `Root`, and then add as many `Matche`s to `Should` as you need, something similar like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Root queryObject = new();
        queryObject.query.@bool.should.Add(
            new Should() {
                match = new() {
                    level = "information"
                }
            });
        queryObject.query.@bool.should.Add(
            new Should() {
                match = new() {
                    level = "error"
                }
            }
        );
        
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryObject));
// Outputs: {"size":1000,"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"level":"information"}},{"match":{"level":"error"}}],"filter":null,"minimum_should_match":0}}}
    }
}

// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Match
    {
        public string level { get; set; }
    }

    public class Should
    {
        public Match match { get; set; }
    }

    public class Timestamp
    {
        public DateTime gte { get; set; }
        public DateTime lt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Range
    {
        [JsonProperty("@timestamp")]
        public Timestamp Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        public Range range { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bool
    {
        public List<Should> should { get; set; }
        public List<Filter> filter { get; set; }
        public int minimum_should_match { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        public Bool @bool { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Root() 
        {
            size = 1000;
            query = new();
            query.@bool = new();
            query.@bool.should = new();
            // skipping the rest ...
        }
        
        public int size { get; set; }
        public Query query { get; set; }
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/YhFM1I

Comment: Thank you! The thing is I need to use the properties that are inside of the json file which would contain the "level" and "information" . I'll add a snippet of the json file if that helps

Comment: Here is an example by looping through your properties. The basic principle is the same, read the values and add them to the List of `Match`es: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yHTuvf